# Archimedean set

Tags: general-topology

right now i'm taking a topology class, where the first chapter is named :"real numbers and sequences": (in french it's called : Nombres et suites réels) , i was wondering if anyone here could clarify a certain term that I often encounter: "an archimedean set", just what is the meaning of an archimedean set? and what does it mean when we say that $\Bbb{R}$ is archimedean?? 
MY THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR Whosoever shall answer these questions

Comment: This term is not standard in English, but I would assume it is in some way referring to the [Archimedean axiom for ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Ordered_fields).  Could you perhaps provide an example of a context in which the term is used?

Comment: first of all thank you very much

Comment: for example we wanted to prove that IN is archimedean

Comment: Re notation: what's with the initial "I"s? It's customary to denote the reals by $\mathbb{R}$ and the integers by $\mathbb{N}$, a la Bourbaki, & surely it's the custom in France & the Francophone world too ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Archimedean" here is referring to a property of ordered groups (in this case, the group of real numbers under addition with the usual ordering). (Using additive notation), an ordered group is archimedean if for any $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, there is a positive integer $n$ such that $nx > y$ (where $nx$ means $x + x + \ldots + x$ with $n$ occurrences of $x$). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_group for more information.

Comment: thx verrry much

Comment: hello again Rob, i have question:  what you said is true if x<y but what if x>y???? does the property hold true in this case??

Comment: If $x > y$, you can just take $n = 1$ to give $nx > y$.

Comment: Hello Rob, can we say that IN is archimedean, I know that IR is?? Thx in advance

Comment: $\Bbb{N}$ can be said to an archimedean ordered monoid - it is not an ordered group.

Comment: So you mean IN is not ordered? I didn't quite get what you said

Comment: It's not a group.